# Blackberry: Return value of Coordinates.distance()

Tags: blackberry, gps, coordinates, distance

I want to know metric of the value returned by Coordinates.distance()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[javax.microedition.location.Coordinates.distance](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/location/Coordinates.html#distance(javax.microedition.location.Coordinates)):

> *public float distance(Coordinates to)*
>   Calculates the geodetic distance between the two points according to the ellipsoid model of WGS84. Altitude is neglected from calculations. The implementation shall calculate this as exactly as it can. However, it is required that the result is within 0.35% of the correct result.
>   *Parameters:* to - the Coordinates of the destination
>   *Returns:* the distance to the destination ***in meters***
>   *Throws:* NullPointerException - if the parameter is null
>   *Since:* JDE 4.0.2